# How to convert varchar to float in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to convert a `varchar` to a `float` and getting the following message.

> Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 41
>   Error converting data type varchar to float. The statement has been terminated.

This is what I tried.

```
ALTER TABLE All_Active
ALTER COLUMN [BE #] float
```

Please tell me there is an easy solution for this.  This should be `float`.  It imported into SQL Server incorrectly.

Comment: You probably have a value in that table & column that cannot be converted to float. Did you check that?

Answer (score 1):

You have a value that is not a valid floating point value.  If you want to alter the column, then first update date it remove such values:

```
update all_active
    set [BE #] = (case when isnumeric([BE #]) = 1 then [BE #] end);
```

Then update the alter table:

```
ALTER TABLE All_Active ALTER COLUMN [BE #] float
```

Comment: I re-imported the file as Excel, instead of CSV, and everything is fine now. Thanks everyone.  It's Saturday and it's sunny out!  Time to stop working!!!